# How to bridge Objective-C initWithError: method into Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, initialization, objective-c-swift-bridge

I have a class defined in Objective-C, whose initializer is `-initWithError:` (the initializer can fail due to a dependence on an outside resource). I want this to bridge into Swift as `init() throws`. The regular initializer inherited from NSObject, `-init`, can be marked unavailable, as I don't want it to be used.

In Objective-C, I have:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject

- (instancetype _Nullable)initWithError:(NSError **)error;

@end
```

This works fine in Objective-C, of course.

In Swift, `-initWithError` gets bridged as `init(error: ()) throws`. This is presumably because removing `withError:` from the method name results in `init()` which conflicts with the inherited plain `-init` initializer. This can be called from Swift like so:

```
let foo = try Foo(error: ())
```

This is strange looking, as the error parameter is void. It would certainly be better if this were imported as `init() throws`. The obvious solution is to mark `-init` using `NS_UNAVAILABLE` in the Objective-C header. Unfortunately, this doesn't work. `-initWithError:` still gets bridged as `init(error: ())`, and trying to call `try Foo()` results in a compiler error saying that `init()` is unavailable in Swift.

Is there a more elegant solution to this so that `try init()` just works?

Comment: You may be able to tackle this using `NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT` — look for that term on this page: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: Thanks, Nate! That would probably work. In this case, this code is in a framework that I wanted to keep in pure ObjC if possible. Rob Napier's answer solves the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can rename the function using `NS_SWIFT_NAME`. In this case:

```
- (instancetype _Nullable)initWithError:(NSError **)error NS_SWIFT_NAME(init());
```

That said, this feels like a compiler bug. I'd suggest opening a [defect](https://bugs.swift.org).

Comment: Thanks, Rob! Not sure why I didn't think of trying that. I'll file a bug against Swift too.